# c# Array returning all elements as null

Tags: c#, arrays, null, return, getter

I have a getter that reads an existing array from another Property of that class and filters out elements with specific Properties.

The problem is, that after reading the Property it returns an array with the correct number of elements but all the containing elements are null.

During debugging I saw that the elements have been inserted correctly.

```
public Member[] Assigned_Users {
    get {
        Member[] _assigned_users = new Member[0];
        //ERROR: foreach gets an array with the correct length, but all null elements
        foreach (Member m in Nested_Users) {
            if (m.Typ != Member.typ.User) continue;
            Member[] _tmp = new Member[_assigned_users.Length + 1];
            for (int r = 0; r <= _nested_members.Length - 1; r++) {
                _tmp[r] = _assigned_users[r];
            }
            _tmp[_assigned_users.Length] = m;
            _nested_members = _tmp;
        }
        foreach (Member m in Members) {
            if (m.Typ != Member.typ.User) continue;
            Member[] _tmp = new Member[_assigned_users.Length + 1];
            for (int r = 0; r <= _nested_members.Length - 1; r++) {
                _tmp[r] = _assigned_users[r];
            }
            _tmp[_assigned_users.Length] = m;
            _nested_members = _tmp;
        }
        return _assigned_users;
    }
}

public Member[] Nested_Users {
    get {

        Member[] _nested_users = new Member[0];
        foreach (Member m in Nested_Members) {
            if (m.Typ != Member.typ.User) continue;
            Member[] _tmp = new Member[_nested_users.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < _nested_users.Length - 1; i++) {
                _tmp[i] = _nested_users[i];
            }
            _tmp[_nested_users.Length] = m;
            _nested_users = _tmp;
        }
        //creates and returns a correct aray, acording to the debugger
        return _nested_users;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:
This code serves the following Purpose.
In the very ancient days of our company, a lot or LDAP groups existed. As many LDAP implementations don't allow to read all the users from a nested LDAP group, my company build their own User management back-end. This is one part of it. 
If a group has a another group assigned (these infos are all stored in an SQL database) It should read the nested groups members and Assign them DIRECTLY to base group.
All of this is just done for services that authenticate against LDAP but don't know how to read users of a Nested group.

But even if `List<Member>` would be the better way to go, as suggested in the comments (and known by be), there should be no reason why the array is filled with null instead of Member objects. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code would be *much* simpler (and more efficient) if you'd just use a `List<Member>` and then call `ToArray` at the end, rather than copying arrays all over the place.

Comment: Fundamentally though, we don't know what `Nested_Members` or `Members` do. Maybe they're returning a bunch of null references. I'd also strongly advise you to read and follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Additional to the answer of Jon Skeet you could use Linq and return `Nested_Members.Where(x => x.typ == Member.typ.User).ToArray()`for `Nested_Users` and `Nested_Users.Concat(Members.Where(x => x.typ == Member.typ.User)).ToArray()`for `Assigned_Users`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think that it will return any null references because in every foreach-loop is the same condition `if (m.typ...`. That will cause in a null-reference-exception. OP doesn't have the problem of that exception.

Comment: @Verarind: That's true, yes. Of course, if we had a [mcve] we could tell more easily...

Comment: `List` and LINQ were invented for this exact purpose...

Comment: I know that I should use List for that purpose, the problem is, that the code rework currently would use up to much time. I will Edit my post to explaine a little bit more what the Code does.

Comment: It wouldn't take that much time. It would just be commenting out the contents of the `get` blocks and replacing each with a single line of code that is much more efficient and easier to read.

Comment: Per the edit: As others have said, there isn't really any reason why this code would cause the arrays to be filled with null. That means that the problem is *not* in this code. So you should find out what code is producing the problem and post that.

Comment: @Abion47 Thank you for your input, but that was the code that I fount that produced the false output. Because Nested_Users only gets called From Assigned_Users. Anyhow, I think I will immediately rebuild all of this code to use List<Member> instead. Thank you all for your help!